# Missing 'Browse' button in Rhythmbox Menu

Tags: rhythmbox

Rhythmbox is missing the <kbd>Browse</kbd>button, in the top menu, as you can see in the screen shot below:

[image]

- Where is the image file located and how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>F11</kbd> when Rhythmbox is running.

It will go in  in Party Mode. Now you can found `Setting` button on top right corner.